# Add field to /settings/sites/new (multi-site)

Tags: multi-site, modules

I would like to add some fields to the site creation on the control panel settings. I know you can add globals for each site, but I think it would be a better process if I could add additional fields.

For example, I'd like to add a select for whether a site (location) is a franchise or corporate.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following you correctly, there currently isn't a way to do this.

Sites are a concept that doesn't support things like fields and field layouts like other elements (Entries, Categories, Matrix Blocks, Tags, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the response, Brad. I was hoping via a Module this would be possible. Perhaps I need to rethink my structure as I was creating 188+ multisites